Клавиатура стирает введённое слово при вводе цифры
Есть инпут, который при вводе в который меняется вводимый текст, например, приводится в верхний регистр: https://jsfiddle.net/dbmh9qoy/


document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e => {
  var val = e.target.value
  var upper = val.toUpperCase()
  
  if (val !== upper) {
    var { selectionStart, selectionEnd } = e.target

    e.target.value = upper
    e.target.selectionStart = selectionStart
    e.target.selectionEnd = selectionEnd
  }
})
<input>



Проблема в том, что на телефонах Сяоми при использовании стандартной клавиатуры Emoji&Font Keyboard если вводимый текст модифицировался, по при вводе цифры или пробела после слова это слово стирается. На скринвидео слово не стирается только если включен caps lock.
Можно как-то исправить?
Скринвидео:

Ошибка не в обработчике события, проблема в том, что значение в input'е вообще меняется программно. Я добавил вывод того, что вообще приходит в обработчик input и видно, что версии с текстом и цифрой одновременно туда вообще не приходит: https://jsfiddle.net/dbmh9qoy/1


Больше похоже на какой-то глюк "Сяоми" или чего-то другого мешающего работе, а потому, прежде чем что-то посоветовать, я бы предложил провести ещё один эксперимент: попробуйте вставлять цифру не в конце, а (сдвинув курсор) в середине и начале вводимого текста. Так же не поленитесь провести эксперимент со вставкой цифры и букв из клипборда в разные места, чтобы быть до конца уверенным. Если дело только в последней цифре, то вам надо лишь добавить проверку на число if(!Number(val[val.length - 1])) чтобы не делать лишний раз toUpperCase()

@stylok, воспроизводится на всех устройствах сяоми и поко с этой клавиатурой. Обрати внимание, что на момент нажатия цифры слово подчёркнуто как текущее вводимое, но при этом никакого автокомплита нет. Код сам ничего не стирает - это клавиатура считает, что цифра заменяет вводимое слово, а не дополняет его. Если передвинуть курсор, то цифра вставится как и должна. PS: К обсуждению не имеет отношения, но ты забыл про ноль.

@stylok, хм.. На пробел та же реакция. Стирается всегда одно подчёркнутое слово, но с вводом в середину этот код вообще не очень дружит. Но даже при вводе слова в середине, портится именно оно (и оно же остаётся подчёркнутым перед этим).

@stylok, сделал более дружелюбный ввод в середину, но на суть вопроса это не влияет - поведение со стиранием текущего слова остаётся.

Если дело действительно только в последней цифре, то, как я и предлагал, попробуйте проверяться так:
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e => {
    let val = e.target.value
    if(!Number(val[val.length - 1]) || val[val.length - 1] !== ' ' ) e.target.value = val.toUpperCase();
});

UPD: Не знаю кто и за что влепил мне минус .) но с учётом вашего добавления внёс правку с проверкой на пробел.
Попробуете, так будем знать куда двигаться. Мой код касается только последнего символа.

Это вообще не в тему. Там уже не будет текста. Важно что значение менялось скриптом до ввода цифры. Но минус не мой.

Я добавил в вопрос пояснение, почему это неверно.

@Qwertiy до этого мы полагали, что дело только в конкретной клавиатуре... а что если это касается целиком swype-методе ввода? Попробуйте найти аналогичную клаву и проверьтесь ещё и там. Если мой код не помогает, то вряд ли мы сможем что-то исправить при помощи JS поскольку клавиатура по смыслу выше по приоритету. Однако, не исключено что в её настройках есть волшебная галочка. И, думаю, в любом случае стоит отправить багрепорт авторам клавы.

При чём тут свайп-метод, если на видео не работают оба - и свайп, и побуквенный? На Realme c GBoard работает. Скриптом надо править не замену, а сделать что-то, чтобы сбросить вводимое слово после изменения.

@Qwertiy пардон, показалось с недосыпу. И всё же. Написал версию того же скрипта, что и выше, но с консольным выводом, чтобы видеть изменения. Такой вывод консоли будет куда нагляднее. Попробуйте.

@Qwertiy если и этот способ не подскажет где проблема, то пожалуй лучше всего будет присмотреться к перехвату ввода с клавиатуры на событии keydown.

Такое ощущение, что ты вопрос вообще не читаешь... И где я возьму консоль на телефоне?

https://i.sstatic.net/LhMgsBAd.png

@Qwertiy но ведь нашёл "консоль" когда прижало?.) Ладно, давай теперь попробуем отловить баг на стадии ввода. Там задействовано два события и вывода: keydown и keyup. В этот раз хотя бы будет видно на какой стадии отваливается. Тыц

Ах да, забыл сказать: с учётом  swype-ввода, возможно понадобится и третье событие — paste. Думаю разберётесь сами.

https://i.sstatic.net/wTQpqPY8.png - кажется, этот вариант работает :)

Т.е., если я правильно понял, то ничего не отваливается? В таком случае вам достаточно оставить событие keyup и пользоваться им.  Но, на всякий случай можете проверить будет ли работать тот код, если контролировать только одно первоначально задуманное событие input. Будет конечно странно, но вдруг?.)

Я ещё обратил внимание, что ты на document подписался, а не на элемент - это тоже надо проверить)

keyup и keydown работают относительно всего документа. Потому мы первым делом отлавливаем форму, а уж потом внутри события проверяем (if), что действия клавиатуры происходят именно внутри input-а.
